# IBM DB2 store the query results in a variable

Tags: sql, function, db2

I am trying to write a function and I need to store some table in a variable. I don't have the type 'Table'
I tried to write something like this:

```
declare t table(a integer, b integer);
set t = (select A, B from MyTable);
```

It does not work.It says there is a syntax error and that there is no table type. What is the solution?
Is there any other way to store the query results in a variable?

Answer (score 2):

Use [declared temporary table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003272.html):

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE session.table_name (a integer, b integer) AS 
(select A, B from MyTable) WITH DATA
```

> The declared temporary table description does not appear in the system
> catalog. It is not persistent and cannot be shared with other
> sessions. Each session that defines a declared global temporary table
> of the same name has its own unique description of the temporary
> table. When the session terminates, the rows of the table are deleted,
> and the description of the temporary table is dropped.